# How to show two or more background colors on CandleStick charts by Highcharts Library?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, candlestick-chart

We are working with highcharts library's Candle Stick chart but have an issue of showing background colors. Is there anyone who has worked on it or any help to make it happen?

You can see a sample in the URL below.

[Sample screen shot with two background colors on Candlestick Chart](http://screencast.com/t/NcUh8Lhy)

Comment: Take a look at plotBands: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands

Comment: Do we have a running example of this for CandleStick?

Comment: the plot band has nothing to do with the series type - it is entirely independent. did you try it out?

Comment: quick example by simply adding a plot band to the default candlestick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/1k0g5sv6/

Comment: The time it takes for band start and band end is in milliseconds. Correct?

Comment: Yes, or whatever your x axis values are - same as your data.